# How to prevent an authentication return URL from dropping what come after the pound sign?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

We have a flash brochure on our site, and the flash plugin use the pound sign (#) as a page referrer.

For example, if I browse the brochure, the url changes to something like this on every page

```
http://site/fr/Brochure/Show/Brochure_Autocar_FR_2012/#/13
```

Now, this site uses authentication. In the event that user is not authenticated at the time, the FormAuthentication in ASP.NET MVC send him to the LogOn page and use the referrer address as the return URL.

```
http://site/fr/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2ffr%2fBrochure%2fShow%2fBrochure_Autocar_FR_2012%2f#/13
```

The problem is when they authenticate, the return URL exclude the #/13, as it is not escaped, and it just browse them to

```
http://site/fr/Brochure/Show/Brochure_Autocar_FR_2012/
```

How can I make sure the data following the pound sign get encoded as part of the return URL?

Comment: You'd have to redirect on the client side, since the pound and stuff isn't even sent to the server. [Phil Haack wrote about this a few days ago](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx); you can probably change his example to emit client-side redirection code instead.